# The most efficient way to find the position (indices) of m smallest elements in a list of n unique numbers without changing the list

Tags: arrays, algorithm, list, iteration, coding-efficiency

Here's a look at my attempt to solve this (algorithm):

```
position := 1
i := 2
k=[]
FOR b = 1, b <= m, b++
    WHILE i <= n DO
        IF i in k
            THEN i++
        IF position in k
            THEN position++
        IF A[i] < A[position]
            THEN position := i
        i++
    RESET i := 2
    ADD position to k[]
    RESET position := 1
```

Now this works, but the complexity for this would be at least n^4 and I would like something way better. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You make a max-heap of size m out of the first m indexes of the array.  When comparing indexes for maintaining the heap, compare the corresponding elements of the array.

Then, for each other index:

- If it is not smaller (by element) than the largest in the max-heap, discard it;
- Otherwise, remove the largest index from the max-heap and put the new one in in.

Throughout the whole process, the max-heap will always contain the indices of the m smallest elements seen.  Total complexity is O(n * log m).

Theoretically, it's better for large m -- O(n) -- to make an array of all indices and just use quickselect, again comparing them by the corresponding elements, but this is worse in the worst case and m is usually small compared to n when this algorithm is needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me why you think your algorithm's time complexity is O(n<sup>4</sup>); the main loop iterates m times, the inner loop iterates O(n) times, and the `i in k` and `position in k` tests in that inner loop are O(m) if implemented as a linear search, or O(log m) if implemented as binary search. That gives a time complexity of O(m<sup>2</sup>n) or O(mn log m) respectively. Those are both better than O(n<sup>4</sup>) because m ≤ n.

The problem can indeed be solved more efficiently. The main idea is to use a priority queue to keep track of the indices of the current m smallest array elements. Initialise the priority queue with the first m indices. Then for each other index, insert it into the priority queue and then remove whichever index has the *largest* array value from the priority queue. Finally, when you reach the end of the array, poll the indices from the priority queue to get them in order.

The length of the priority is always at most m + 1, so if you use a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) as a priority queue, then the insertion and remove-largest operations each take O(log m) time. Those are done for (n - m) array elements. The initial stage of inserting m indices into the heap, and the final stage of polling m elements from the heap, take O(m log m) time. This makes the overall time complexity O(m log m + (n - m) log m), which simplifies to O(n log m).